# Cannot read property of 'fn' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, http-status-code-404

Getting these error codes on my github pages. I have these as my order of loading scripts:

```
<script src="../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/index.js"></script>
```

Here are the error messages:

```
GET https://tmolano.github.io/CareerMod4/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js 404 ()
index.html:115 GET https://tmolano.github.io/CareerMod4/node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js 404 ()
util.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at util.js:56
    at util.js:10
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ util.js:56
(anonymous) @ util.js:10
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
```

Heres my page: https://tmolano.github.io/CareerMod4/

Other than the order of loading, what else could be causing this?

Comment: The first line clearly shows the problem: `GET https://tmolano.github.io/CareerMod4/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js 404 ()`. The path does not exist and the jQuery library is not loaded.

Comment: @RachelGallen "load jquery scripts at the top of your html , not the bottom". That doesn't change anything. The path to jQuery library does not exist!

Comment: @undefined in the website, the scripts are loaded at the end of the page

Comment: @RachelGallen You can load the scripts at the end of a page. OP just needs to move them into the end of the `body` tag.

Comment: @RachelGallen ah...I forgot to add my node_modules folder. Also thanks for pointing out tag location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible reasons for this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

1. invalid reference to the file addresses or missing files (Your case).
2. Duplicate reference to the Jquery.
3. Overriding $ sign of Jquery in 3rd party libraries.
4. Using Jquery functions before inserting Jquery (Not your case).
5. Using deprecated syntax for load,error,unload on WINDOW element in jquery without `on`

Answer (score 0):

Update 2023:

I used this code snippet to fix all the problems I had!

As of bootstrap 5 they will require you to use their [Proper](https://popper.js.org/) . And here I use **[Bundle](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)** and it still works well with all functions

for nextjs 13

```
  <Script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js" />
  <Script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2" />
  <Script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
    crossOrigin="anonymous"
  />
```