# Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, three.js

I tried to replicate this blog post [Create A Realistic Self-solving Rubik's Cube With Three.js](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/realistic-rubik-cube.html) in a Wordpress page. However, I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at jquery.cube.threejs.min.js?ver=5.5.3:21
```

This is how I load the necessary javascript files in my `functions.php`

```
wp_register_script('threejs', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r123/three.min.js', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_enqueue_script( 'threejs' );

wp_register_script('cubejs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/libs/jquery.cube.threejs.min.js',array( 'jquery' ));
wp_enqueue_script( 'cubejs' );

wp_register_script('cubeCode', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/cube.js',array( 'jquery'  ));
wp_enqueue_script( 'cubeCode' );
```

And the `cube.js` file is just this

```
(function($) {
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {       
        const myCube = jQuery(".cube").cube();
        myCube.execute("(U R U' R') (U R U' R') (U R U' R') (U R U' R') (U R U' R') (U R U' R')");
    })
})(jQuery);
```

When I actually check the source code of the page, the scripts are in the right order

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='.../wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp' id='jquery-core-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r123/three.min.js?ver=5.5.3' id='threejs-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='.../assets/libs/jquery.cube.threejs.min.js?ver=5.5.3' id='cubejs-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='.../assets/js/cube.js?ver=5.5.3' id='cubeCode-js'></script>
```

Comment: Is that an old jquery version?  Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52451388/cannot-read-property-of-fn-of-undefined

Comment: It has the default version of 5.5.3 version of Wordpress.

Comment: That is the version of Wordpress, but the version of jQuery is 1.12.4 as you can see from the script tag that ends in wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp

Comment: On the demo page, there are just three js files included like this:   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.cube.threejs.js"></script>  Why do you think you have 4?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is using an old version of jQuery. Read this and try using wp_enqueue_scripts https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/

```
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jquery_enqueue' );
```